# There should be an option to sort the teams by the number of members

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, old-teams

Suddenly I discover there're quite "popular" teams (i.e. ones having many members) on the last page (when sorting by "created").

I think there should be a tab which sorts the teams by the number of members (in descending order). It'll be called, probably, "members" or "popular".

> [image]

Comment: I also wouldn't mind seeing one for "modified" (or "activity") - just like questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is now a new sort for number of members on the team.

Answer (score 3):

That's a good idea, and we found ourselves looking for it too. This should be added soon!